# How do I make an action happen only once per n steps?

Tags: python, game-development

I tried using the steps variable, but it didn't get any results. Is there a way to make the addition of the asteroids so that it happens once per n steps?

```
asteroids = Group()
spaceship = RegularPolygon(200, 350, 15, 3, fill='white')
lasers = Group()
counter = Label(0, 380, 20, size=20, bold=True, fill='white')
def onMouseMove(mouseX, mouseY):
    spaceship.centerX = mouseX
def onMousePress(mouseX, mouseY):
    lasers.add(Rect(mouseX, 320, 2, 15, fill='lime'))
def onStep():
    asteroids.add(Circle(randrange(0, 400), 0, 30, fill='gray'))
    for laser in lasers:
        laser.centerY = laser.centerY-30
        if (laser.centerY < 5):
            lasers.remove(laser)
    for asteroid in asteroids:
        asteroid.centerY = asteroid.centerY+3
        if (asteroid.centerY > 399):
            asteroids.remove(asteroid)
```

Comment: Normally you'd give the event its own counter, or use a modulus operator: `%` and check for even divisiblity (zero remainder)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and try to give proper *context* for the problem. What are "steps"? Why should `onMouseMove`, `onMousePress`, `onStep` have any special meaning? I assume it's because you are using some specific game engine. Please *say which one*, and use the tags to get the attention of specialists. (And please *don't* tag irrelevant languages.)

Comment: "I tried using the steps variable" I don't see any such variable in the code, and I don't see any reason why it would actually count the number of steps. "Is there a way to make the action on line 12" Why not just tell us what action you want to control, instead of making us count the lines?

Comment: If you are using a steps variable, you must make it global so it persists between calls to OnStep.

Comment: Is this a PyGame-based project? We might assume that OnStep() is a built-in callback found in PyGame but you might need to detail this in your post, as mentioned by @KarlKnechtel

Comment: It is a Python game, and what I’m trying to do is make the asteroids appear only once per n steps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` to determine whether the number of iterations is divided by `n` with no remainder.
Note that you should not modify the original container during traversal. Traversing the copy of the container is a good habit:

```
n = 5   # According to your situation.
for i, laser in enumerate(lasers.copy(), 1):
    laser.centerY -= 30
    if i % n == 0 and laser.centerY < 5:
        lasers.remove(laser)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you are trying to do?  There is a counter that decrements until zero.  At zero, do the update and reset the counter.

```
asteroid_update = 0
asteroids = Group()
spaceship = RegularPolygon(200, 350, 15, 3, fill='white')
lasers = Group()
counter = Label(0, 380, 20, size=20, bold=True, fill='white')
def onMouseMove(mouseX, mouseY):
    spaceship.centerX = mouseX
def onMousePress(mouseX, mouseY):
    lasers.add(Rect(mouseX, 320, 2, 15, fill='lime'))
def onStep():
    global asteroid_update
    # I don't know how the next line fits into your 5th step or every stop logic
    asteroids.add(Circle(randrange(0, 400), 0, 30, fill='gray'))
    for laser in lasers:
        laser.centerY = laser.centerY-30
        if (laser.centerY < 5):
            lasers.remove(laser)
    if asteroid_update:
        asteroid_update -= 1
    else:
        asteroid_update = 5 # reset counter
        for asteroid in asteroids:
            asteroid.centerY = asteroid.centerY+3
            if (asteroid.centerY > 399):
                asteroids.remove(asteroid)
```

Comment: I got two “This is not allowed outside of the Sandbox” errors.

Comment: @JonnyGulmatico I have no clue what "the Sandbox" is.